# SQL Query - Need Elegant Solution

Tags: sql, sql-server

I feel like I am a decent SQL programmer; however, I came upon a situation that I can't seem to find an elegant solution to solve.  There are two tables in my database, a tmp_media table and a tbInventoryMedia table.  I want to delete all of the media from tbInventoryMedia that does not exist in the tmp_media table.  However, there is a distinct column called VIN - some VINs can have the same media as others.

Example:

```
tmp_media
Vin MediaId
 X  20223  
 Y  54235
 Z  20223

tbInventoryMedia
vin  MediaId
 X   20223
 X   32131
 Y   54235
 Z   20223
```

In the above example, the vin of X would be deleted where mediaId is 34131.

Lastly, tmp_media does not contain an exhaustive list of all VINs, only those that have been recently processed.  So there will be other media in tbInventoryMedia that needs to be left alone.  Only VINs that are located in the tmp_media table are to have any data removed.

If additional clarification is needed, let me know - I imagine that this is very confusing.

Comment: You state: " tmp_media does not contain an exhaustive list of all VINs, only those that have been recently processed. So there will be other media in tbInventoryMedia that needs to be left alone." How would you differentiate a media that should be deleted vs. one that should be left alone when both will be missing from the tmp_media table?

Comment: If a media has a VIN that is not located in the tmp_media it should not be deleted.  The system is fairly complex, we process huge amounts of cars and only a couple get updated at a time.  When they are updated the cars are put into the tmp_media table for media processing.  Sometimes an updated car can have an image removed so this process will verify that images no longer tied to the car are removed from the database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should illustrate my take on your requirements:

```
create table #tmp_media (VIN char(1), MediaID int)
create table #tbInventoryMedia (VIN char(1), MediaID int)

insert #tmp_media
select Vin = 'X', MediaId=20223
union select 'Y',  54235
union select 'Z',  20223

insert #tbInventoryMedia
select vin = 'X',  MediaId = 20223
union select 'X', 32131
union select 'Y', 54235
union select 'Z', 20223
union select 'A', 20223
union select 'A', 12345

select * from #tbInventoryMedia

delete im
from
    #tbInventoryMedia im
    join (select distinct VIN from #tmp_media) as uq on uq.VIN = im.VIN
    left join #tmp_media m on m.MediaID = im.MediaID and m.VIN = im.VIN
where m.MediaID is null

select * from #tbInventoryMedia


drop table #tmp_media
drop table #tbInventoryMedia
```

I've added some data for the "A" VIN, which I beleive should be left alone. In this example only `X, 32131` gets removed